# Something out of nothing: How can points of zero size make a plane?

Tags: geometry, intuition

I was wondering about what makes a plane, it were the lines and lines are made up of points. But we know that points by definition have 0 volume. Then how can a 0 size add up to make a finite plane.

Is there any other definition to plane which does not include hard to define infinite lines and points?

Comment: For what a point is is a matter of definition.  One calls an element of a metric space a point, e.g.  And points may have a positive "volume" in context of Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Why is your question about 2-dimensional planes? Can't you ask the same question about 1-dimensional lines?

Comment: Because "volume" is only **finitely** additive and there are an infinite number of points in a line.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Can you please explain a bit more?